# What is the algorithm to calculate some values padding?

Tags: file, structure, padding, reverse-engineering

I reversing some game file to translate it and already understand everything, aside of how to determine some blocks padding.

For example, I have this in one file (two entries by 36 byte each and then zero padding. 96 bytes total):

```
01 08 01 80 00 00 00 09 00 00 08 C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 08 01 80 00 00 00 09 00 01 94 C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

And this in another (1 entry 36 bytes and then zero padding. 64 bytes total):

```
01 08 01 80 00 00 00 09 00 00 04 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I tried to start devising 64 by 62, 60, ..., [32], ..., [16], ..., [8], ..., [4], [2].

The digits in [] the ones that 96 and 64 can be divided without rest.
But the unpadded sizes (72 and 36) also can be divided by 2, 4, 8.
What is the padding? How to calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the number of `00` padding bytes should be calculated like follows:

```
padding(num_bytes)=ceil(num_bytes/32)*32-num_bytes
```

then we get for first case

```
padding(2*36) = 24
```

24 additional padding bytes (and 96 in total) and for second case

```
padding(36) = 28
```

28 additional padding bytes (and 64 in total).

Comment: But why you divide num_bytes by 32? This is exactly the digit that I need to determine.

Comment: Because that's the only information your examples suggest. Also it seems plausible to pad to a multiple of 32 bytes on common systems.

Comment: Btw it cannot be 16 or 8 bytes because that would contradict your examples.

Comment: but what if I have 4 entries 12 bytes each (48 bytes) and zeros on the end, so in total 68 bytes. I looking for a general solution. step by step. How to determine that 32 number.

Comment: From the original examples we have total number of bytes 64 and 96 so the _greatest common divider_ is 32 and therefore my formula would work. If there are other cases like 68 bytes in total then I am afraid that there is not enough information to deduce a general solution here (but are you really sure that all 68 bytes a related to padding, e.g. it could be 64 bytes plus 4 bytes belonging to next block?)

Comment: I think I understand now that I need to determine greatest common divider.

Comment: In second example I have 4 blocks by 12 bytes each. Then 20 bytes of zeros. useful data is 48 bytes and total is 68.